# Can I take my daughter with me for my ILR appointment even if she is not an applicant?

Tags: united-kingdom, children

I am applying for my ILR next week. I have opted for same day decision and my appointment is in Croydon center. The appointment is quite early in the morning considering the time it would take for me to travel to the appointment center. I would not be able to drop my daughter at her day care before then. I also unable to make alternative care arrangements for her.  So I am planning to take her with me. She is not an applicant as she is not eligible for ILR yet.

My question is, can they let my daughter in along with me if she is not one of the applicants on the grounds that I am unable to make arrangements for her care?

**UPDATE**

I am done with my ILR appointment. They allowed my daughter to be taken with me. They did not even ask if she is one of the applicants or not.

Comment: Ambiguous but [this page](https://www.gov.uk/ukvi-premium-service-centres/book-an-appointment) says "you can bring anyone else you need."

Comment: @mkennedy although the link is for those applying for a visa and from outside the UK, I understand that Lunar House in Croydon has a playroom in the waiting area, masses of children everywhere.

Comment: @Dorothy Because OP mentioned same day processing, I looked at premium processing which is for applications in the UK and includes Croydon. Good news about the waiting area though.

Comment: @mkennedy that page is not for ILR applications, however, the premium service centers listed there are the same as for ILR so I am going to assume that the rules about letting in small children are not going to change based on the application type of the main applicant.

Comment: @mkennedy no problem; I get that logic... and yes, Suhas, the centre is teaming with little ones.